# Not null field in db table hidden in JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a legacy SQL table with deprecated not null column

```
CREATE TABLE legacy_table {
    name character varying(255),
    deprecated_col integer NOT NULL
}
```

Now I want to create new Entity to map that table but without that deprecated column. Is there any way/trick to omit that not null column? For example by passing value 0 as a default value or by some annotation/orm xml configuration?
Unfortunately from technical reason and backward compatibility I cannot remove that column from database.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private String name;
    private Integer deprecated_col; 


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // deprecated_col has no accessor 
}
```

Comment: Depends on your database. If you have Oracle, you can omit the mapping in your code and create an INSERT trigger in the database that sets your default value. Alternatively, you can map the column and use @Generated, set the value to your default value and not provide Setters/Getters.

Comment: if your deprecated column is `NOT NULL` then it will always store 0 if you don't pass any value, as hibernate will automatically intialise it

Comment: Thanks guys I will try Your advice. I work with PostgreSQL

Comment: When I removed deprecated_col from entity and added default value on SQL column deprecated_col integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Insert command works without problems.